# Where is the right place in the project to put a resource text file to read in an iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to read a text file in a new App, but when it runs the file cannot be found.

I'm not sure where in the project I should put the file. I dragged it into the Assets folder from finder, but it's still not found. I looked at a similar question but the answer was in a much older version of Xcode and didn't solve my problem. I'm using Xcode 11.1

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BibleTable", ofType: "csv") {
    do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
            print(contents)
        } catch {
            print("Error reading file BibleTable.csv")
        }
    } else {
        print("File not found")
}
```

It gives "File not found"

Comment: You could create a Resources folder in the navigation pane in Xcode and drag files there.

Comment: Check the target membership of `BibleTable.csv`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Z0A.jpg

Comment: The Xcode version does not apply for the answer to this question. And the file shouldn't be included as an asset, but rather as part of the target. This will ensure it's part of your app when it's built. I'd recommend reading https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1

Comment: Also, whomever suggested closing this as "Opinion based" is using the vote functionality incorrectly. This is a perfectly legitimate question (that most likely have several duplicated answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anywhere you fancy in the Bundle other than the assets folder, just as long as you your app (and any test target) is selected as a target in the File Inspector's Target Membership component.

Comment: Yes that worked. I read it could go anywhere, but it didn't say not the assets folder. I find the swift documentation is not clear or well defined. Lucky there is stack overflow. I'm new to swift but have done a lot in php and c